# What is the proper way to declare a simple Timestamp in Avro

Tags: hive, timestamp, bigdata, avro

How can we declare a simple timestamp in Avro please.

type:timestamp doesnt work. So I actually use a simple string but I want it as a timestamp. (this is my variable: 27/01/1999 08:45:34 )

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Avro's logical type:

```
 {"name":"timestamp","type": {"type": "string", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}
```

Few useful links:

[Avro timestamp-millis](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/spec.html#Timestamp+%28millisecond+precision%29)

[Avro Logical types](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki/Advanced-usage#logical-types)

[Hortonworks community question about Avro timestamp](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/80010/best-practice-json-to-avro-data-type-preserving.html)

Comment: Thank you. Can I manipulate dates and times later with this format? (extract year, month or day? or more?)

Comment: Sure, you should be able to extract any part from timestamp, etc.